# WPML Default Language User Meta

Tags: users, user-meta, multi-language, plugin-wpml

I'm having a super hard time finding the names of the default user meta that's included with WPML. WPML has a setting for "Default Admin Language" under every user's profile. I'd like to access this on the front end so all my users are automatically switched to their selected language on login. I can't figure out the correct key to use to access the custom meta.

[image: Screenshot of WPML option in user profile]

So far, I've tried:

```
<?php 
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'icl_user_admin_language', true); 
?>
```

and

```
<?php 
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    var_dump(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'icl_user_admin_language')); 
?>
```

but both of these options come up empty. I'm assuming it's because I'm not using the correct key for the user meta, but I've tried googling and I've even dug through the documentation, and I can't find mention of this. Anyone have some insight as to how I can grab the language that a user has set from the front end of the site?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the correct key was icl_admin_language. I was able to drop the key from the "get_user_meta" function and then print_r the variable. This showed me all custom user meta which I could then sift through for my desired key.